# create batch script file with user prompt and xcopy

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch script file to help an administrative assistant in my work group. Let's call him John.

John receives many CDs daily from clients containing architectural drawings as PDFs. Each CD is unique. John assigns it an Application Number, and creates a new folder on the network drive with the Application Number as the folder name. John then copies all the files on the CD to the newly created folder name. He repeats this process for every CD he receives.

I don't have any programming experience so I hope you can lend me a hand. Here's what I wrote below but it's not working. I get an "Insufficient memory" error. A new folder name based on the user input is correctly created on the network drive path but it's empty.

Thanks for your help! FYI, I'm running Windows 7 64-bit

```
@echo off
echo Welcome team member!
pause
set /p anumber=Type in the Application Number then press Enter key when done. 
mkdir "S:\ARCH\Active Forms and Files\Submittal Floor Plans\%anumber%\"
:: e:\ is the CD drive path
set source=e:\
:: S:\ is a network drive
set destination="S:\ARCH\Active Forms and Files\Submittal Floor Plans\%anumber%\"
xcopy %source%\* %destination%\* /s /e /l /h /i >nul 
pause
exit
```

Comment: The `xcopy` command is not going to copy anything unless you remove the `/L` option -- see `xcopy /?`...

Comment: Yup, I realized that now.

Comment: If I want to compare the content of the CD against the destination folder, a sort of error check to make sure everything is copied correctly, how can I accomplish this via batch file? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were setting the variable `%source%` to `e:\` which was the read by the interpreter as `E:\\*` when used in `%source%\*`, leading to an invalid directory. The same was being done to the `%destination%` variable.

**Updated Script:**

```
@echo off
set "networkFolder=S:\ARCH\Active Forms and Files\Submittal Floor Plans"
set "CDDrive=e:"

echo Welcome team member!
:input
    set "applicationNo="
    set /p "applicationNo=Enter the Application Number and press ENTER: "
    if not defined applicationNo goto :input
    set "newLocation=%networkFolder%\%applicationNo%"
:actions
    md "%newLocation%"
    xcopy %CDDrive%\* "%newLocation%" /s /e /i /h>nul 

echo Completed!
pause
```

Comment: Sam, this is amazing! I can't thank you enough for your help! You have saved countless hours of monotonous task for my friend. You've made my day. I'm very happy! Btw, I incorrectly used the xcopy /l switch so no files were copied. Once I removed the /l switch, everything copied fine.

Comment: `E:\\ `is actually not invalid and points to the root directory of `E:`, like `E:\ `does too...

Comment: Good to know about "E:\\". Also, thanks for cleaning up my post, aschipfl. It reads more clearly. :)

Comment: I think the `/I` option makes perfect sense here to avoid the File/Directory prompt; the `/L` option however needs to be removed to actually copy something...

Comment: I concur on /i option. Per Microsoft's website, "By default, xcopy prompts you to specify whether Destination is a file or a directory."

Comment: Is there a way to message other user directly on Stackoverflow?